# How to match a given regex pattern to get a substring from a String

Tags: java, regex, string

i have a string for ex- "Abc Xyz Def OSSV-1810-017466-AB01 Def Utv"
How to write a regex that mathches formats like "OSSV-1810-017466-AB01" and extract  only that from any given string?

**What is tried:**

```
public class RegexTest { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        String str = "Abc Xyz Def OSSV-1810-017466-AB01 Def Utv"; 
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z\\-\\0-9\\-\\0-9\\-\\^A-Za-z0-9]"); 
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str); 
        System.out.println(matcher.toString()); 
        if(matcher.find()){ 
            System.out.println("found" + matcher.group(1)); 
        } 
        else{ 
            System.out.println("not found"); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please post your code that you've tried. There are plenty of examples online to do this.

Comment: Also what logic would give this outcome?

Comment: Hi , Kartik i'm unable to get the exact regex pattern right for that substring

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kindly take a look around and see how to ask a proper question in this community.

Comment: Perhaps this may do the job for you: `String theStuffINeed = "Abc Xyz Def OSSV-1810-017466-AB01 Def Utv".split("\\s+")[3];`

Comment: @DevilsHnd that substring could be any where in that given String,could you please suggest a regex for that pattern ?

Comment: Please at least post your group matching code and we'll fix your regex.

Comment: @Kartik
public class RegexTest {
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     
    String str = "Abc Xyz Def OSSV-1810-017466-AB01 Def Utv";
  
  
   Pattern pattern =  Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z\\-\\0-9\\-\\0-9\\-\\^A-Za-z0-9]");    
   
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
  System.out.println(matcher.toString());
  
  if(matcher.find()){
   
   System.out.println("found"+matcher.group(1));
  }
  else{
   System.out.println("not found");
  }
 }

}

Comment: Well...I'm certain it wont really matter what is given you because the rules will change as you receive more information since you're not telling anyone what the specific string rules are. Is the substring identical in every string? Does the substring always start with `OSSV`? Are there always 4 alpha characters in uppercase at the start of the substring.....on an on and on. Be specific. In any case this should cover the basics: `(?i)[A-Z]{4}-\\d{4}-\\d{6}-[A-Z0-9]{4}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern `[A-Z]{4}-\\d{4}-\\d{6}-[A-Z]{2}\\d{2}`.

Also change `matcher.group(1)` to `matcher.group(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input="Abc Xyz Def OSSV-1810-017466-AB01 Def Utv";

    String regEx="([a-zA-Z ]*)((?:[A-Z]{4}-)(?:[0-9]{4}-)(?:[0-9]{6}-)(?:[A-Z0-9]{4}))([a-zA-Z ]*)";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regEx).matcher(input);            

    if(matcher.matches()) {         
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```